# Get Batch (.bat) File run during a specific time range

Tags: batch-file, time, scheduled-tasks

I want to have my .bat file from 9:00 am to 6:00 am the next day.  This is my code shown below:

```
powershell -window minimized -command ""
@echo off

 cls
:start 
cscript DisplayBoard.vbs "FilePath\macro.xlsm"
goto start
```

I tried adding the set hours one and the time code but neither one worked with my code.  Can someone help?

Update this is the code i tried

```
powershell -window minimized -command ""
@echo off
SET hour=%time:~0,2%

SET shouldrun=True
IF %hour% geq 9 SET shouldrun=False
IF %hour% leq 6 SET shouldrun=False

IF "%shouldrun%"=="True" (
    CALL "S:\BlueIris\Telegram_Upload\Telegram_upload.cmd"
)

cls
:start 
cscript DisplayBoard.vbs "S:\OPER\SHARE\Display Board\170 370 TV\macro.xlsm"
goto start
```

Comment: Hi.  The code you provided doesn't appear to be related to time at all.  If you tried doing something else, please provide *those* details.  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I added the code I tried